# what is meant by multiprocessing and how it works?

Tags: multiprocessor

what is difference between cores, CPU, threads and processor on linux system ? please explain the difference

Comment: Related: [Task Manager is saying the system is running with over a thousand threads](http://superuser.com/q/615814/53590) on SuperUser (disclaimer: the accepted answer is mine :)).

Comment: You should edit the question in your title (which is indeed too broad) to match what you are asking later which I guess can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

A core is a CPU is a processor. Machines can be single-core (one CPU) or multi-core (more than one CPU). A processor is another name for a CPU.

Because there are typically many processes running on a computer -  all requiring CPU resources - the computer must schedule how the competing tasks are processed. On a single-processor (single core) machine, scheduling is performed by allocating small time slices to each process. The performance of the machine and the short span of time (milli-seconds) that each process is running makes it appear to the user that processes run concurrently.

The distinction between a thread and a process can vary depending on the operating system - this answer attempts only a basic explanation. Generally a process can contain many threads. The operating system can schedule each of the threads separately. Each of the processes' threads share the processes code  (each thread has it's own instruction register) and also share the processes data. Each thread however has it's own stack segment. The call stack keeps track of the return point following a function call.

A multi-core machine (having two or more CPUs) will not only schedule processes by timeslicing. It can also run a separate thread per core. Threads running in separate cores are (unlike a single core machine which gives the impression of concurrency with time-slicing) truly concurrent.

Multi-threading gives better computer processing performance. A few years ago the continual improvements in CPU performance slowed ([Moore's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) no longer applied) and since then CPU performance technology has been driving by multi-core and multi-threading technologies.

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect. A processor is not a CPU or core but a chip, i.e. a microprocessor. I guess also your third paragraph is off topic, you are describing threads from an operating system point of view while the question is likely about hardware threads, i.e. what is called hyperthreading or chip-multithreading.

Comment: The CPU is a chip. What is the difference between a processor and a CPU?

Comment: The CPU is a chip only in single core configurations. A CPU (Central Processing Unit) is one of the internal components of a microprocessor. Those having more than one are called multi-core processors, i.e. multi-cpu processors. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit

Answer (score 1):

- A processor is a physical chip you plug to a socket. Early processors were mostly composed of a CPU. Later, MMU (virtual memory management), FPU (floating point), caches and sometimes GPU (Graphic) were added to the processors.
- A core is a CPU. A processor can have one or more cores. A two core CPU is roughly equivalent to two single core processors, although shared components might reduce the gain if a component is a bottleneck or on the opposite and more commonly improve the performance because of a faster internal communication between cores.
- A core might support more than one hardware thread, i.e. allows multiple context of executions (mainly registers) to be handled concurrently. This improves performance too despite the fact all threads share the same CPU. The gain is due to faster context switching and near concurrent execution due to the memory access latency.